# Server Error (500) On Password Reset Request when deployed Django Project at Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have deployed my Django Project on Heroku https://billpayy.herokuapp.com/. When I try to reset the password, it gives an Error 500 page. The Password Reset functionality works fine locally but gives this error when deployed. Also, couldn't decode much from the **Error Logs**:

```
2021-05-30T12:08:10.012088+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/account/password_reset/" host=billpayy.herokuapp.com requ
est_id=90b04f79-c813-4efa-8d2a-aa922d0bcae9 fwd="27.4.64.168" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=765ms status=500 bytes=403 protocol=http
2021-05-30T12:08:10.012273+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.30.51.66 - - [30/May/2021:12:08:10 +0000] "POST /account/password_reset/ HTTP/1.1" 50
0 145 "http://billpayy.herokuapp.com/account/password_reset/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, l
ike Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36"
```

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for billing_site project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

import os
import django_heroku
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['billpayy.herokuapp.com']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'billingapp.apps.BillingappConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'bootstrap4',
    'crispy_forms',
    'bootstrap_datepicker_plus',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'billing_site.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'billing_site.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'site-home'

LOGIN_URL = 'site-sign-in'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.account, name='site-account'),
    path('register/', views.register, name='site-register'),
    path('sign_in/',
         auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/sign_in.html'),
         name='site-sign-in'),
    path('log_out/',
         auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/log_out.html'),
         name='site-sign-out'),
    path('password_reset/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset.html'),
         name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_done.html'),
         name='password_reset_done'),
    path('password_reset_confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_confirm.html'),
         name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('password_reset_confirm/done/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='users/password_reset_complete.html'),
         name='password_reset_complete')
]
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: please share a log of your console

Comment: for this you should set DEBUG to True

Comment: Solved! The problem was with DisplayUnclockCaptcha Settings for my Google Account. Enabled that and things worked fine for me. Got the clue by setting DEBUG to True as @MahdiZarrintareh recommended. Thanks!

Comment: @Umang Thadani can you add that as an answer? Others might stumble in the same situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!
The problem was with DisplayUnclockCaptcha Settings for my Google Account. Enabled that and things worked fine for me. Got the clue by setting DEBUG to True.

3 checks to ensure.

1. Make Sure that the E-Mail Account from which you want to send Password Recovery Emails is given **Less Secure App** Access [here](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1&rapt=AEjHL4N2yr1v6BCKxgoXkazhySJC6ODtwuTtbD9jGErQYcQJw_SxDRRMFKRtAGRcS3TcYVzcRSLp7BcxWGoPAk8ik12dvwXyvw).
2. An Additional step that has something to do with DisplayUnlockCaptcha. Make sure that is enabled [here](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha).
3. Open you Gmail account -> Settings -> See All Settings -> Forwarding and POP/IMAP -> Enable IMAP.

The above solution did work for me.